# Почему Spring Application закрывается? Process finished with exit code 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

При старте приложения, выкидывает Process finished with exit code 0
Я знаю, что если завершилось с кодом "0", то все отработало успешно, но у меня стоят маппинги для пользовательского ввода, и я не могу даже на него перейти, ибо приложение завершается

Так же пробывал добавлять бесконечные циклы, что-бы хоть как-то запустить, но не хочет.

Вот что выдает консоль IDE:

```
2023-11-28T23:27:24.838+02:00  INFO 35399 --- [           main] c.h.h.HelpambulanApplication             : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-11-28T23:27:25.167+02:00  INFO 35399 --- [           main] c.h.h.HelpambulanApplication             : Started HelpambulanApplication in 0.503 seconds (process running for 0.847)
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Код контроллера:

```
@Controller
public class GenerateController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/generateQRCode")
    public String generateQRCode(@RequestParam("data") String data, Model model) throws WriterException, IOException {
        String qrCodeImage = generateQRCodeImage(data);
        model.addAttribute("qrCodeImage", qrCodeImage);
        return "result";
    }
    private String generateQRCodeImage(String data) {
        try {
            Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hintMap = new HashMap<>();
            hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 0);
            QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200, hintMap);
            return QRCodeUtil.convertBitMatrixToBase64(bitMatrix);
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758996/intellij-process-finished-with-exit-code-0-when-spring-boot-run